# Where can i find a List of IdentityErrors related to User registration?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I want to try to filter the Identity Errors during the Sign Up process, so then i can show them in a more friendly way in the View for instance behind the respective input, and not showing them by using `asp-validation-summary="All"`.
See the below code as a reference

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp(SignUpViewModel viewModel)
{
    var usernameErrors = new List<string>();
    var passwordErrors = new List<string>();
    var unknowErrors = new List<string>();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var client = new Client
        {
            UserName = viewModel.Id, FullName = viewModel.FullName, BirthDate = viewModel.BirthDate.Value,
            Email = viewModel.Email
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(client, viewModel.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return RedirectToAction("SignIn", new {DidHeJustSignUp = true});

        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            if(error.Code.Contains("UserName"))
                usernameErrors.Add(error.Description);
            if(error.Code.Contains("Password"))
                passwordErrors.Add(error.Description);
            if(error.Code.Contains("unknownError"))
                unknowErrors.Add(error.Description);
        }
        viewModel.UsernameErrors = usernameErrors;
        viewModel.PasswordErrors = passwordErrors;
        viewModel.UnknowErrors = unknowErrors;
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

I'm not trying to filter all but at least the most obvious ones. I'm new to Identity so my apologyze if the question is dumb for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the `UserManager.CreateAsync` method will call [PasswordValidator](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordValidator.cs) and [UserValidator](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserValidator.cs) method when creating user.

So the normal error is as below:

```
IdentityErrorDescriber.PasswordTooShort

IdentityErrorDescriber.PasswordRequiresDigit

IdentityErrorDescriber.PasswordRequiresLower

IdentityErrorDescriber.PasswordRequiresUpper

IdentityErrorDescriber.PasswordRequiresUniqueChars

IdentityErrorDescriber.InvalidUserName

IdentityErrorDescriber.DuplicateUserName
```

If you have enabled the require Email opinion add below check:

```
IdentityErrorDescriber.InvalidEmail

IdentityErrorDescriber.DuplicateEmail
```